# How do I get this Python code to execute properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, fizzbuzz

The following Python code is not working and I am unsure as to why, and unsure as how to correct it. Thanks in advance!

the code should print the word “fizz” when number is a multiple of three
print the word “buzz” when number is a multiple of five
print the word “fizzbuzz” when number is a multiple of both three and five

```
for number in range(1, 100):
 message = ''
 if number % 3 != 0:
 message =+ "Fizz"
 if number % 5 != 0:
 message =+ "Buzz"
 if number % 5 == 0 or number % 3 != 0:
 number =+ str(number)
 print(message)
```

Comment: 1. fix the indent (there's supposed to be a tab for all the lines in the if block) 
2. number += str(number) won't work, you can't add a number and a string in python

Comment: The answer fixes the syntax problems, but I think the code still has some logic bugs.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
    for number in range(1, 100):
        message = ''
        if number % 3 != 0:
            message += "Fizz"
        if number % 5 != 0:
            message += "Buzz"
        if number % 5 == 0 or number % 3 != 0:
            message += str(number)
        print(message)
```

`=+` should be `+=`, python uses indentations to separate code blocks, and i think `number =+ str(number)` at then end should have been `message += str(number)`

Answer (score 1):

The `=+` needs to be `+=`, and there are a few `==` that should be `!=` and vice versa.

```py
for number in range(1, 100):
  message = ''
  if number % 3 == 0:
    message += "Fizz"
  if number % 5 == 0:
    message += "Buzz"
  if number % 5 != 0 and number % 3 != 0:
    message += str(number)
  print(message)
```

Also, this can be condensed way down:

```py
for number in range(1, 100):
  message = ''
  message += "Fizz" if number % 3 == 0 else ''
  message += "Buzz" if number % 5 == 0 else ''
  print(message if message else number)
```

Another thing is that `range(1, 100)` is exclusive of 100, so you need to change that to 101 if you want to include 100